# Pivot Table/Chart

Tags: pivot-table, excel-tables

I have a large spreadsheet with multiple columns.  I need to create a pivot table/chart to show the difference in the "Prev RFS Month" to the "New RFS month" Counts, so I have a column with the count per month of "Prev Month" and a column with the Count of "New RFS" and chart lines are next to each other.  I have tried everything and I cannot get this to work.  PLEASE HELP

I have tried creating a pivot table with Prev RFS and New RFS in Row and Column and count of each in value.  I have put both in rows and count of both in value and they are giving me the same for each, which isn't the case.